# Stack png's with css inside a div with transparency

Tags: html, css, png, transparency

I have several divs, each containing 2 transparent images that should be stacked.

I have tried with setting the first as a background. For some reason the img is not transparent.

Then i tries to stack the images inside the div. But i still have the transparency problem.

Check the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Epby4/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
            <div class="ring" id="ring57">
            <a class="images" href="/rings/57/edit">
                 <img src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/band/img/29/thumb_ringblack.png" width="160">
                <img class="cut" src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cut/img/11/thumb_roundcut.png" width="160" style="background-color : transparent;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ring" id="ring66">
            <a class="images" href="/rings/66/edit">
                 <img src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/band/img/27/thumb_band_yellow.png" width="160">
                <img class="cut" src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cut/img/14/thumb_ring4_center.png" width="160" style="background-color : transparent;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ring" id="ring67">
            <a class="images" href="/rings/67/edit">
                 <img src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/band/img/27/thumb_band_yellow.png" width="160">
                <img class="cut" src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cut/img/15/thumb_ring5_center.png" width="160" style="background-color : transparent;">
                </a>
            </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the css :

```
div.ring {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:160px;
    height:130px
}
div.ring img {
    position:absolute;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `png`'s aren't transparent. They have a white background.

They are also corrupted and cant be opened in photoshop.

I suspect you actually saved them as `jpeg`'s but with a `png` file extension

Comment: Ok thank you very much :-) Really sorry about this but you are right. These are the thumbs versions and for some reason the bg is not transparent. Actually the code worked with the original (large) images. Thx again !